# a stupid question on "set"

Tags: set-theory

Hello,

I come across the following definition "the intersection of the empty class of subsets of a universal set is the universal set".

However, I could not have an intuition about it, could you give me some advice?

Thank you very much.

Sincerely,

Bond

Comment: Try asking on math.stackexchange.com; here, your question is off-topic, as explained in the FAQ. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is something like this: take $x$ in the universal $\Omega$ set. $x$ will be in the intersection $\cap_{\lambda}S_{\lambda}$ if it's in each set $S_{\lambda}$ of the intersection.  But that's automatically true for an empty class of sets, since there are no sets in the intersection. So $x$ is in the intersection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. 

It is much clearer now, but .. I still do not get it..